# How do I efficiently block advertisements on a Mac?

Tags: macos, webserver, adblock

I'm currently trying to block most advertisements using a combination of AdBlock (for regexes) and the /etc/hosts file. However, trying to bypass the issue where blocked ads just show up as an error message (xxxxx.yyy not found), I found a few lightweight servers, whose only purpose is to serve a 1x1 GIF when requests are made. However, I feel they are inefficient in my workflow - I have to manually open two Terminal windows, start two servers (one for HTTP and one for HTTPS), and type my password twice (the server requires superuser privileges).

Is there a similar solution that is less effort-expensive (and more "automatic")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Software

Have you considered taking a look at [GlimmerBlocker](http://glimmerblocker.org/)?

> GlimmerBlocker **is implemented as an http proxy**, so the stability of Safari isn't compromised because it doesn't use any hacks. It is even compatible with all other browsers and other native Mac OS X applications which uses http, e.g. NetNewsWire. The proxy runs on the mac and not on a central server like most proxies.
>
> Because GlimmerBlocker doesn't hack Safari, there is a few things it isn't able to do: adding a block by right-clicking an image, stopping pop-unders, and filtering cookies from 3rd party sites. But you win a lot in stability, and GlimmerBlocker provides much easier methods for adding your own modifications to pages by adding css rules, pieces of Javascript or by transforming the html before Safari receives it. So I'll hope you're happy with the tradeoff.
>
> If you can program in Javascript you'll be able to add your own modification to pages. See the included filters for examples, e.g. adding a download link to YouTube.

### Manual solution

Have you considered setting up the two instances of your web-server software to simply start up at boot? I don't see why you shouldn't be able to make it automatic.

How about [a login hook?](http://support.apple.com/kb/Ht2420).

> Note that with Mac OS X 10.3.x and 10.4.2 or later, you can use the alternative method at the bottom of this document instead, if you wish. For Mac OS X 10.4 and 10.4.1, you should always use the following steps:
>
> #### 1. Open Terminal (Applications/Utilities).
>
> #### 2. In the Terminal window, type:
>
> ```
>     sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /path/to/script
> ```
>
> (where /path/to/script is the full path to the script that you want to execute when a user logs in—it doesn't have to be in the user's Home directory).
>
> This modifies the /var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow file.
>
> #### 3. Type your password at the prompt, then press Return.